# Xcode error file not found in derived data (App_name).app/(App_name)

Tags: xcode, react-native

i am using **xcode@14.3.1** the app running fine in old mac after i change my machine to mac m2 and try to run on simulator it gives error while build debug **error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/device/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App_name.app/App_name'.** Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

i tried lot of solutions in stack overflow delete the derived data folder etc but didn't work kindly any one help me on this i already spent a whole day